# How to deal with the numeric keypad in a canvas-based application?

Tags: java-me

How to deal with the numeric keypad in a canvas-based application? I want all the input features of text controls (like, switch between ABC/Abc/abc/123/T9, special chars input and stuff) without text controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real way to do that. The best you can find is to duplicate by code all functions. The only library I'm aware of that gives you something like that is LWUIT, but it is way to heavy, and you don't get predictive text